# Chat and the API are slow or appear to be completely down

Tags: support, chat, outage

Me and several others are experiencing periodic chat outages. Chat is currently entirely dead for me on all three domains. The API is also significantly slowing down the main site. Can barely flag stuff. Meta.SO also blipped for me. Chat is currently the only part that refuses to load, primarily due to timeouts.

Judging by a quick question on the meta Discord, it might be specific to European users, but I don't have much information aside it being nearly dead or entirely dead for several people, and it's been wobbly for about 15 minutes to half an hour.

Comment: We're investigating some issues  - https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1338855674692988928

Comment: @Taryn Hopefully this doesn't have anything to do with Nick fixing those `0 = 1` SQL queries... :-P

Comment: @TylerH haha, thankfully this doesn't appear to be on the SQL side of things

Comment: It is affecting the US too, Zoe, so it's probably everywhere. I also can't seem to get some Snippets to load.

Comment: I was the one suggesting it might be Euro (seemed to be the only commonality at the time) but the errors have crept in everywhere now

Comment: Asia, completely down; It's back ...the moment I commented